# How to avoid cache invalidation/"Analysis cache invalidated, auxclasspath changed" on every run of PMD?

Tags: maven, pmd

Everytime I run PMD through the Maven Plugin with an analysis cache set up I'm seeing the log message

```
[INFO] Analysis cache loaded
[INFO] Analysis cache invalidated, auxclasspath changed.
[INFO] Analysis cache updated
```

Judging from the speed of the analysis with and without cache (files present) the cache isn't used (which is how I understand invalidation in this  context). I'd like to use it in order to make the analysis faster.

I'm using PMD as standalone binary in a commit hook as well where I needed to specify `-auxclasspath`. I found it in a forum post, used it and it seems to work, however I don't understand it and find no information about it. The commit hook runs for modified files only and doesn't use a cache.

My Plugin configuration is

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pmd</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <rulesets>
            <ruleset>/pmd.xml</ruleset>
        </rulesets>
        <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
        <includeTests>true</includeTests>
        <analysisCache>true</analysisCache>
        <analysisCacheLocation>${env.HOME}/code-analysis/pmd-analysis-cache/${project.name}</analysisCacheLocation>
        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.pmd</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmd-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

There's an [issue report](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/1025) which allows to make some guesses about what auxclasspath is and why the message is produced, however it doesn't provide an explanation or instructions how to use it right.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand… you are running PMD from Maven in normal builds AND from CLI in a commit hook? If you run it through Maven twice, is the second run still saying it's invalidated?

Comment: @Johnco Thanks for you interest. Clarified in the question.

Comment: Could you provide a sample project? I can't seem to reproduce this…